# Change embedded destination port in compiled application

Tags: c++, tcp, port, reverse-engineering

I have a compiled client application without the source code. It connects via TCP to my server on port 7777 (this is the destination). I would like to change the application to use a different port and there is no settings on the client to change it easily. This leads me to believe that it is hard-coded into the application.

I have messed around a little bit with it but I am not a professional reverse-engineer and this proves to be too difficult for me to figure out alone. Is what I am trying to accomplish even possible?

Comment: What OS ? Have you tried a firewall/nat based approach ? (like iptables -A OUTPUT --destination your_server -p tcp --dport 7777 -j DNAT --to-destination your_server:8888)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you compile this without the source code? That question aside.

Look for 7777 (hex 1e61) i.e. 1e followed by 61 (or the other way around) in a binary editor and change it.

Comment: It was compiled by someone who is no longer around, but the program is still needed until a replacement is made. I have already tried in a hex editor to no avail.

Comment: OK, I want to apologize. I tried again and changed to little endian and mass replaced all instances of 7777 in a hex editor and it worked. Now I just need to narrow it down. Thanks

Comment: He is not around but the source is? Why not recompile it then? It can't be that hard (until you try it).

Comment: @PepsiMmmm Urgh. You have _mass replaced_ all occurrences of 7777 ?? I suppose that you just should have replaced the right one, where the socket is opened. You might have broken other things for occurrences of 7777 that are not related to a socket opening. :oS

Comment: @Seki yea there were about 12 occurrences. I will just narrow down which one I needed. Luckily nothing broke before I tried to connect haha

Comment: @RedX unfortunately the source has gone MIA.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the platform and the available tools. If you can use `strace` on your environment, you can process the output and determine where the port is opened, and with that information go back to the binary, disassemble it, locate the function that is making the call, and try to determine how the port number got there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html) to create a TCP forwarding proxy. From [socat examples](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLES):

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:www TCP4:www.domain.org:www
```

> installs a simple TCP port forwarder. With TCP4-LISTEN it listens on local port "www" until a connection comes in, accepts it, then connects to the remote host (TCP4) and starts data transfer. It will not accept a econd connection.

It is a less flexible approach than using `iptables` because the socat proxy must run on that server your client connects to.